# T-SQL ORDER BY & INSERT causes "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The `CalculateDistance` function returns a float. The function works when using `SELECT` & `WHERE` however when adding `ORDER BY` or `INSERT INTO` I get `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.`

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[CalculateDistance]
    (@Longitude1 Decimal(8,5),
    @Latitude1   Decimal(8,5),
    @Longitude2  Decimal(8,5),
    @Latitude2   Decimal(8,5))
Returns Float
As
Begin
Declare @Temp Float
 
Set @Temp = sin(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * sin(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) + cos(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Longitude2/57.2957795130823 - @Longitude1/57.2957795130823)
 
if @Temp > 1
    Set @Temp = 1
Else If @Temp < -1
    Set @Temp = -1
 
Return (3958.75586574 * acos(@Temp) )
 
End
```

```sql
DECLARE 
    @startLongitude decimal(8,5) = -96.75841,
    @startLatitude decimal(8,5) = 40.78117

DECLARE @returned TABLE (
    Distance FLOAT
)

--INSERT INTO @returned(Distance) --< Causes Error
SELECT dbo.CalculateDistance(@startLongitude, @startLatitude, z.Longitude, z.Latitude) Distance
    FROM Zips z
    WHERE dbo.CalculateDistance(@startLongitude, @startLatitude, z.Longitude, z.Latitude) < 251
--    ORDER BY Distance --< Causes Error
```

Zips Table Snippet:

```
ZipCode|City               |State|Country|Population|Latitude |Longitude |TimeZone|
-------+-------------------+-----+-------+----------+---------+----------+--------+
00501  |HOLTSVILLE         |NY   |US     |         0|40.817923|-73.045317|5       |
00544  |HOLTSVILLE         |NY   |US     |         0|40.788827|-73.039405|5       |
00601  |ADJUNTAS           |PR   |US     |     18570|18.196747|-66.736735|4       |
00602  |AGUADA             |PR   |US     |     41520|18.352927|-67.177532|4       |
00603  |AGUADILLA          |PR   |US     |     54689|18.458585|-67.129867|4       |
00604  |AGUADILLA          |PR   |US     |         0|18.488773|-67.147741|4       |
00605  |AGUADILLA          |PR   |US     |         0|18.428900|-67.153800|4       |
00606  |MARICAO            |PR   |US     |      6615|18.166734|-66.939233|4       |
00610  |ANASCO             |PR   |US     |     29016|18.294649|-67.130034|4       |
00611  |ANGELES            |PR   |US     |         0|18.285600|-66.969800|4       |
00612  |ARECIBO            |PR   |US     |     67010|18.388009|-66.665279|4       |
```

Example Distance Values:

```
168.49747310531987
168.49747310531987
117.96381879830946
117.96381879830946
82.12701472670007
120.86004491231444
```

I don't have a good understanding as to why I get the error and where exactly the conversion is occurring. I've tried to CAST and CONVERT the Distance into int and numeric before ordering and inserting however received the same error.

Comment: As we don't have a copy of your scalar function (`dbo.CalculateDistance`) we can't replicate this problem. Can you include the definition please?

Comment: Do you have any other conditions in your `WHERE` clause that you omitted to mention? Or is `Zips` a view that itself contains a `WHERE` clause? Usually this type of thing happens when a problematic expression can be evaluated either before or after some rows are filtered out

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear. Added the CalculateDistance function. Zips is a table.

Comment: CAn you provide some sample data too please? I dumped some of your values in, but didn't get an error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C2BMqASb) We really need a [mre] here.

Comment: Added some data from the Zips table. Reading through the minimal reproducible example page.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your problem with the sample data ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Kl0U3Z_)) and so have voted to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: What `@@version` of SQL Server by the way? Inlining of Scalar UDFs has had [various bugs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) so you may be encountering one of them if on a version supporting that and not up-to-date with all CUs

Comment: Thanks for trying @Larnu. Its Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64).

Comment: Even on a 2012 instance I have access to (while 2022 goes through additional testing), it doesn't error, @Rex . You need to provide a full [mre] here.

Comment: Still trying to reproduce the example on a different sql instance but can't seem to.

Comment: Whelp sorted out the issue. I still do not understand the issue but if I call the exact same CalculateDistance function but from a database other than the one containing the Zips table it works.

Comment: Can you provide the XML for the execution plan for both working and non working cases? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ - may be possible to see what is going on there

Comment: Are you sure you're using the exact code posted in the question? The only way I can get your error message, `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric`, is by doing something like declaring the function's return type to be `decimal(9,5)` while declaring the `Distance` column in the `@reurned` table variable to be `decimal(8,5)`.

Comment: @MartinSmith That helped alot. The Long a Lat variables are decimal(18,6) rather than Decimal(8,5).
Works: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkxuyTt9j
Doesn't Work: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByBpJpF5j

Comment: In the "doesn't work" plan there is a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT(decimal(8,5)` that doesn't appear in the "works" plan

Comment: In the "works" plan the variables are implicitly cast to `decimal(18,6)` and there is no casting of the `[Zips].[Longitude]`, `[Zips].[Latitude]` at all. What are the datatypes of `[Zips].[Longitude]` and `[Zips].[Latitude]`? Also are these execution plans definitely generated against exactly the same database?

Comment: The zips table Long and Lat are `decimal(18,6)`. Both plans are on the same SQL instance using the same zips table. The difference is that the working one uses the `CalculateDistance` function from a difference database and take in `decimal(18,6)` instead of `decimal(8,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `[dbo].[CalculateDistance]` function variables from `Decimal(8,5)` to be the same as the `[Zips].[Longitude]` and `[Zips].[Latitude]` datatype (`Decimal(18,6)`) solves the issues. Thanks everyone from your help and time.